# SQL Server Log Shipping and Master Key

Tags: sql-server, encryption

We have a SQL Server 2008r2 database that uses encryption. We are log shipping the db to a secondary backup. Decryption is failing on the secondary server. The secondary backup does not appear to have a master key.

What is the order of operations for setting up the encryption on the secondary server?

Do I need to make a backup of the key on the primary and then use that file to restore it to the secondary, or do I just need to create an identical key on the secondary server?

We tried the following command on the secondary server and got an error message:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
```

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

The user who ran the script is a dbo admin on the box.

Comment: The name of the key in the error message is odd to me. IIRC, the system generated keys start with '##'. If you query master.sys.symmetric_keys, do you see a key by that name? If so, back it up and restore it on your secondary server.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from MSDN....

Back up the service master key at the primary. This key will be restored at the secondary

BACKUP SERVICE MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'path_to_file' 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'

RESTORE SERVICE MASTER KEY FROM FILE = 'path_to_file' 
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password' [FORCE]

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151224.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190337.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187972.aspx

Comment: Doesn't the force option result in data loss (as mentioned in the documentation)?